# How to replace push notification with new received notification (containing same notification id) in IOS 12

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am working on ios rich push notifications. And want to replace previously received notification in notification tray with newly received notification if the key (e.g "notification_id") is same in payload. I have tried solution mentioned in "https://medium.com/the-guardian-mobile-innovation-lab/how-to-replace-the-content-of-an-ios-notification-2d8d93766446" and it is working with ios 11 but not with ios 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass same **collapse_id** with the notification you want to replace.
Here is the description of  **collapse_id**

> Only one notification with the same id will be shown on the device.
>   Use the same id to update an existing notification instead of showing
>   a new one. Limit of 64 characters.

Comment: Taimoor  can you please share your payload. because my notification with same collapse_id is not getting replaced.

Comment: payload in where pass ?